# Flash remote images

Tags: flash

I want to understand something if it is possible to do it in flash movie. 
I want to make flash animation with let say 4 pics. The animation will be used as an advertisement on other sites.

But i want the images in the flash movie to be changed from time to time. Thus i want the images to be loaded from my server while the movie is been shown on other sites.

I want to know if this is possible in flash.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How is that a programming question?

Comment: Sometimes it is difficult to find where to post the right question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you use the Flash IDE, this is generally a good place for this kind of questions: http://forums.adobe.com/community/flash/flash_general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, common and very easy to do. The easiest way is to use use the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) class to load the images.

Of course, the swf must know which images to [load](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html): basically you could have an XML file (or a plain urlencoded text file) containing the paths to your images. Or you can hardcode the path inside the code, but this may be a poor solution in terms of flexibility.

Maybe you should do a little bit of research about crossdomain.xml too.